# How do I access the Volumes directory in Macintosh HD?

Tags: macos, finder, permission, folders

I am trying to get into the Volumes directory.

Hidden files are being shown.

However, the Volumes folder won't let me access it, it's "greyed out". How can I bypass this?

Comment: In a Terminal, what is the output of: `ls -l / | grep Volumes`

Comment: drwxrwxrwt@  4 root  admin      136 Mar  3 20:20 Volumes

Comment: In a Terminal, what is the output of: `ls -l /Volumes`

Comment: total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  1 Mar  3 20:15 Macintosh HD -> /

Comment: If things are wonky with a OS X system directory like /Volumes, perhaps /Applications/Utilities > Disk Utility > Repair Permissions will find & fix it.

Comment: Can you `cd /Volumes` from the Terminal?

Comment: Yes. then the ls output is : Macintosh HD

Comment: I agree with IconDaemon, the next step is to use Disk Utility and Repair Disk/Repair Permissions.

Comment: I'll try that and see how it goes

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I want to remove an older version of a boot manager (rEFInd) which installs under Volumes/ESP/EFI. Hopefully repairing disk permissions doesn't screw anything up.

Comment: Err. I did Disk Repair and I still can't get into Volumes

Comment: In a Terminal, if you execute `ls -al /Volumes` do you see the directory you're looking for?

Comment: No, I don't see what I am looking for. I think I need to step back from this and figure out more carefully what I need to do. However, I still don't understand why I can't access Volumes in Finder!

Comment: Volumes:
is basically a directory at the root level of your system, that stores all your hard drives (if you have more than one) that is all it should have in it (no files)

Comment: @Buscar웃 The /Volumes directory is used to create mount points for mounted volumes, it really does not as you said "stores all your hard drives (if you have more than one)".  Storing something would imply containing the contents and that's certainly not the case.  Also you said "that is all it should have in it (no files)" however the /Volumes directory can contain a .DS_Store **file**.

Comment: Based on everything you've posted, the folder you're looking for in `/Volumes` just isn't there to begin with. As noted in the rEFInd instructions, you may have to use `diskutil list` to locate the EFI partition and `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp` (where `disk0s1` is the EFI partition) to mount it.

Comment: @douggro What does the second command do? (sudo mount ...)

Comment: `mount -t msdos` tells the system to mount the directory as an MS-DOS volume from the location defined in the `/dev` listing to the location `/Volumes/esp`.

Comment: @douggro Why does it need to mount as an MS-DOS?

Comment: Most likely because the EFI partition is a simple filesystem partition and MS-DOS is all that is needed.

Comment: Well the output of running `sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp` : `mount: realpath /Volumes/ESP: No such file or directory`. So it seems not quite there yet.

Comment: I'm placing a short hold on this since it looks like troubleshooting isn't done yet. Let's move the discussion to [chat] and see about editing this into one, two or three clear questions once we've collectively figured out what's being asked here.

Comment: Skywalker - please consider editing the post to explain what "get into" means. If [this is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), just explain what the end result you wish to achieve. It appears you might be asking how to do X since you think it will get you closer to Y.

Comment: @bmike I will gladly edit the post. I think this is an XY problem. I don't quite know how to add this to Ask Different Chat, I've never used that feature before. So if someone could do that for me and explain there that would great. Edits coming soon.

Comment: Chat will need some reputation for you - so try to edit the post and get it reopened and upvoted. You don't say what you do in /Volumes, so that might be the Y - I look forward to seeing the edit.

Answer (score 5):

We need more specifics about what is going wrong. Do you have admin privileges on your computer?

Have you tried ⌘-⇧-G from the Finder and then typed `/Volumes` in that window?

[image]

You can also open a Terminal window, type `cd /Volumes` and then if that works type `open .` (a period).

If none of those work, then you need to set up that account with privileges to access root folders, but I think it should at least ask you to authorize when you try Go to Folder...

---

Edit: Just a guess, but from the Finder, click on the Home icon to get to your user menu. Then go to the *View* menu > Show View Options (or press Command-J). At the bottom, click to show Library folder. (If you don't see this option, you probably have the wrong folder selected.)

Comment: Yes I have admin privileges (a.k.a the sudo password). I tried the Command-shift-G in Finder then typing in "/Volumes" but it doesn't bring me to right place. That brings me to "Macintosh HD". I want to be in Macintosh HD and then the hidden Volumes directory beneath it. The terminal command didn't do anything. When I run sudo cd /Volumes I remain in my home directory (where we see Documents, Pictures, etc.). I apologize, I can't upload screenshots at the moment my Imgur account is not working (fml.. I know).

Comment: `sudo` just isn't necessary here as the permissions on `/Volumes` are 1777, everyone has read, write and execute.

Comment: @skywalker, you can upload images directly.

Comment: Apparently not because I can't access the Volumes directory from Finder. (Macintosh HD -> Volumes) No can do.

Comment: @skywalker `sudo cd` will never work -- the `sudo` command runs `cd` as a subprocess, that subprocess changes directory to wherever you told it... and then exits, leaving the parent process (your shell) in the same place it was to begin with.

Comment: Can you see the Library folder? Try the edited part of my answer